# How to get focusin for all textbox? using javascript event not using jquery

Tags: javascript, events, this, focusout, focusin

> Hello Guys, I need help a little bit. Can anyone help me, how to use
>   this keyword in my case?

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtFirstName">Your name</label>
        <input id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="inputBox" />
    </div>              
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtEmail">Email address</label>
        <input id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" type="email" autocomplete="off" class="inputBox" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">                            
        <select id="drpPosition" name="drpPosition">
            <option>I would describe my user type as </option>
            <option>Web developer </option>
            <option>Web designer </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtPassword">Password</label>
        <input id="txtPassword" type="password" class="cool" autocomplete="off" class="inputBox" />
        <small>Minimum 8 characters</small>
    </div>       
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Next" />
    </div>
</form>
```

> This is my JavaScript Code:

```
var inputFirstName = document.querySelector('.inputBox');
console.log(inputFirstName);
this.addEventListener('focusin', inputAddClassFunc);
this.addEventListener('focusout', inputRemoveClassFunc);

function inputAddClassFunc(event){ 
    console.log(this);     
    this.previousElementSibling.classList.add('active');    
}
function inputRemoveClassFunc(event){    
    var hasValue = this.value;    
    if(!hasValue) {
        this.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
    }    
}
```

> When I focusin into the textbox, active class will be added to it's
>   sibling's lable And in my case, It only works in first textbox but not
>   for all textbox. How can I use "this" to works for all textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use event delegation instead - add `focusin` and `focusout` listeners to the form, and when the event fires, if the target of the event is one of the `.inputBox`es, carry out the logic to change the class of the `event.target.previousElementSibling`:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('focusin', inputAddClassFunc);
form.addEventListener('focusout', inputRemoveClassFunc);

function inputAddClassFunc(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('.inputBox')) {
    event.target.previousElementSibling.classList.add('active');
  }
}

function inputRemoveClassFunc(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('.inputBox')) {
    var hasValue = event.target.value;
    if (!hasValue) {
      event.target.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtFirstName">Your name</label>
    <input id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="inputBox" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtEmail">Email address</label>
    <input id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" type="email" autocomplete="off" class="inputBox" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="drpPosition" name="drpPosition">
      <option>I would describe my user type as </option>
      <option>Web developer </option>
      <option>Web designer </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtPassword">Password</label>
    <input id="txtPassword" type="password" autocomplete="off" class="inputBox" />
    <small>Minimum 8 characters</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Next" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Also note that if you want the `txtPassword` element to have the `inputBox` class, you should change

```
<input id="txtPassword" type="password" class="cool" autocomplete="off" class="inputBox" />
```

to

```
<input id="txtPassword" type="password" autocomplete="off" class="inputBox" />
```

(remove the duplicate `cool` attribute)

Comment: what a great job. Thank you so much to save my time. You are an expert in JavaScript.